# Spinner method confusion

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm having some difficulty with transferring a previously developed Java applet into an Android app. I am using Eclipse as an IDE. There seems to be subtle nuances and differences between the two languages.

It's a calculator program that will allow the user to choose a material type and a shape type from two spinners. If they choose rectangle, the diameter text field is supposed to switch to disabled. If they choose cylinder, then the height and width fields are supposed to switch to disabled. Then the calculate button does the math, and the clear button resets everything. The Java applet works like a charm, so I'm not certain what the problem is here. Help is much appreciated!

Below is the most important excerpts of the code:

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import org.****.materialcalculator.R;



public class MaterialCalculator extends ActionBarActivity {

public Spinner materialDD;
public Spinner shapeDD;
DecimalFormat d = new DecimalFormat("#");


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_material_calculator);

    materialDD = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.materialDD);
    shapeDD = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.shapeDD);
    Button btnCalculate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCalculate);
    Button btnClearAll = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnClearAll);
    final EditText txtDiameter = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtDiameter);
    final EditText txtLength = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtLength);
    final EditText txtWidth = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtWidth);
    final EditText txtHeight = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtHeight);
    final EditText edtTxtTotprice = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtTxtTotprice);
    final EditText edtTxtWeight = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtTxtWeight);

    btnCalculate.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String strmaterialDD = materialDD.getSelectedItem().toString();
            String strshapeDD = shapeDD.getSelectedItem().toString();

            double number1 = Double.parseDouble(
                txtDiameter.getText().toString());
            double number2 = Double.parseDouble(
                txtLength.getText().toString());
            double number3 = Double.parseDouble(
                txtWidth.getText().toString());
            double number4 = Double.parseDouble(
                txtHeight.getText().toString());

            //If 'Rectangle' is selected:
            if(strshapeDD.equals("Rectangle")) {
            //6061
            if(strmaterialDD.equals("Aluminum 6061")) {
                edtTxtTotprice.setText("Total Price: $" 
                        +d.format((0.098*(number2*number3*number4)*3.06)));}               
            //2024
            if(strmaterialDD.equals("Aluminum 2024")) {
               edtTxtTotprice.setText("Total Price: $" 
                       +d.format((0.1*(number2*number3*number4)*5.61)));}

            //7075
             if(strmaterialDD.equals("Aluminum 7075")) {
                 edtTxtTotprice.setText("Total Price: $" 
                         +d.format((0.101*(number2*number3*number4)*7.85)));


          //If 'Cylinder' is selected:
             } else if(strshapeDD.equals("Cylinder")) {
               //6063 
               if(strmaterialDD.equals("Aluminum 6063")){
                   edtTxtTotprice.setText("Total Price: $" 
                            +d.format((0.098*(((number1/2)*(number1/2))*3.14159*number2))*3.06));}
                //2024
              if(strmaterialDD.equals("Aluminum 2024")){
                  edtTxtTotprice.setText("Total Price: $" 
                            +d.format((0.1*(((number1/2)*(number1/2))*3.14159*number2))*5.61));}
               //7075
              if(strmaterialDD.equals("Aluminum 7075")) {
                  edtTxtTotprice.setText("Total Price: $" 
                            +d.format((0.101*(((number1/2)*(number1/2))*3.14159*number2))*7.85));}
               //Mic-6
               if(strmaterialDD.equals("Mic-6")) {
                   edtTxtTotprice.setText("Total Price: $" 
                            +d.format((0.097544*(((number1/2)*(number1/2))*3.14159*number2))*2.28));}

               //17-4
               if(strmaterialDD.equals("17-4")) {
                   edtTxtTotprice.setText("Weight (lb):" 
                            +d.format((0.282*(((number1/2)*(number1/2))*3.14159*number2))));}
               //1018
               if(strmaterialDD.equals("Steel 1018")) {
                   edtTxtTotprice.setText("Weight (lb):" 
                            +d.format((0.2843*(((number1/2)*(number1/2))*3.14159*number2))));}
               //4140
               if(strmaterialDD.equals("Steel 4140")) {
                   edtTxtTotprice.setText("Weight (lb):" 
                            +d.format((0.282*(((number1/2)*(number1/2))*3.14159*number2))));}
               //OI
               if(strmaterialDD.equals("OI")) {
                   edtTxtTotprice.setText("Weight (lb):" 
                            +d.format((0.282*(((number1/2)*(number1/2))*3.14159*number2))));}
               //Grade 2
               if(strmaterialDD.equals("Titanium Grade 2")) {
                   edtTxtTotprice.setText("Weight (lb):" 
                            +d.format((0.163*(((number1/2)*(number1/2))*3.14159*number2))));}
               //B360
               if(strmaterialDD.equals("Brass 360")) {
                   edtTxtTotprice.setText("Weight (lb):" 
                            +d.format((0.307*(((number1/2)*(number1/2))*3.14159*number2))));}
               //Acetal
               if(strmaterialDD.equals("Acetal")) {
                   edtTxtTotprice.setText("Weight (lb):" 
                            +d.format((0.0564*(((number1/2)*(number1/2))*3.14159*number2))));}
               //CPVC
               if(strmaterialDD.equals("CPVC")) {
                   edtTxtTotprice.setText("Weight (lb):" 
                            +d.format((0.05635*(((number1/2)*(number1/2))*3.14159*number2))));}
               //PVC
               if(strmaterialDD.equals("PVC")) {
                   edtTxtTotprice.setText("Weight (lb):" 
                            +d.format((0.0564*(((number1/2)*(number1/2))*3.14159*number2))));}
               //UHMW
             if(strmaterialDD.equals("UHMW")) {
                 edtTxtTotprice.setText("Weight (lb):" 
             +d.format((0.0564*(((number1/2)*(number1/2))*3.14159*number2))));}

              }}}}});
```

This part right here, I believe, is part of my problem. In my Java program, I was able to use the `ActionPerformed` event to tell the program which fields to enable.  Which is based on the shape that was selected. As of right now, it does nothing and leaves all fields enabled.  This may lead into most of the errors I'm receiving.

```
    if (shapeDD.equals("Rectangle"))
        txtDiameter.setText("0");
    if (shapeDD.equals("Rectangle"))
         txtDiameter.setEnabled(false);
    if (shapeDD.equals("Cylinder"))
        txtWidth.setEnabled(false);
    if (shapeDD.equals("Cylinder"))
        txtWidth.setText("0");
    if (shapeDD.equals("Cylinder"))
         txtHeight.setEnabled(false);
    if (shapeDD.equals("Cylinder"))
        txtHeight.setEnabled(false);



        btnClearAll.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            //@Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                edtTxtTotprice.setText("Total Price: $");
                edtTxtWeight.setText("Weight (lb):");
                txtDiameter.setText("");
                txtLength.setText("");
                txtWidth.setText("");
                txtHeight.setText("");
                materialDD.equals("Aluminum 6063");
                shapeDD.equals("Rectangle");
            }});
        };

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.material_calculator, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

When I run this through the emulator, I keep getting the error in my LogCat of `NumberFormatException invalid double: ""` after the 'Calculate' button is clicked. This seems to indicate that a field is empty when it's not supposed to be, but I believe that error may lie in the code above.

Is parseDouble an acceptable method in Eclipse? 
How do I get the shapeDD spinner declarations to work without `onActionPerformed`?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm making the assumption (and a quick one at that, just glanced through this) that getText().toString() is giving you an empty string which, when parsed, is giving you bad double. Try checking to make sure the field isn't empty before you get the text.

Comment: Yes, that's because the spinner shapeDD is not auto-filling the appropriate blanks with zeros as directed. It's supposed to fill in some blanks with zeros and not allow them to be edited. It's not because I cannot translate the following from Java into something equivalent in Eclipse:
    shapeDD.setSelectedIndex(#);
and I'm also not sure how to translate the following into Eclipse: shapeDropDownActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt). Because that is what I used in Java to implement lines 1-12 of my second block of code up there.

Comment: Correction: it IS because I cannot translate those lines.